# How to get markers coordinates from GMAP into a Drupal CCK field?

Tags: google-maps, drupal-6, cck, google-local-search, drupal-gmap

I'd like to implement a GMAP into a Drupal 6 CCK form. I already have the GMAP module installed, and what I'd like to have is a CCK field in which coordinates from selected markers from GMAP are entered.

The ideal map would be one like this : http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#localsearch_with_markers. I have big issues on implementing this script into a form (don't know where (in a `hook_form_alter()` I suppose?), with (`drupal_add_js('$js_code', 'inline')` ?

So if I could have some experts advices, this would be awesome :-)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the [Location module](http://drupal.org/project/location) and [GMap module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) will give you all of that functionality (plus an awful lot more) without a single line of code...it's got to be the way to go!